# Discord.js bot doesnt see messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

My bot is supposed to send a message in console when message is sent. But it doesn't trigger after I am writing a messages on discord server.

Bot is online and joined the server. He also got all needed permissions.

**CODE:**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: false, intents: ["0x0000000000000008"]});

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Loaded!');
  bot.user.setActivity('Running a test, hopefully.');
});

bot.on("Message", (message) => {
  console.log('Message!');
});

bot.login("bot token");
```

Comment: What intent does the bit `"0x0000000000000008"` resolve to? You'll need the guild messages intent to receive messages

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect event name for the incoming message (`Message`). Correct name of this event is depends on your version of `discord.js`. If you're using version `v13.*` or greater, you should use [`messageCreate` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate):

```js
// Correct event name for discord.js v13+
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    console.log('Message received! Message content: ' + message.content);
});

// And this event is deprecated
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log('Message received! Message content: ' + message.content);
});
```

As an additional note regarding how you initialize your `client`: you should use [`Intents` class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/Intents) on v13 or `GatewayIntentBits` on v14 for better readability. You can read more about intents for v13 [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#intents) and changed initialization for v14 [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#common-client-initialization-changes).

Answer (score -2):

In your event listener you have logged a string, not the message object

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log('Message!'); //incorrect - string, will log 'Message!'
    console.log(message.content); //correct - content property of message obj, will log message content
});
```

You will also need to add the correct intents. Since `MessageContent` is a privileged gateway intent, you'll need to enable it in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Check out a good article on this in the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents).

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, from the OP's question "Bot doesn`t write in console" it seems they're having issues with getting the listener to emit not an issue with logging message content

Comment: I see, however I have given a guaranteed solution for both possible issues: being that the intents aren't correct; being that the `console.log` wasn't logging the message content.